# Row with the biggest sum in matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a program where I enter numbers to make a matrix. Then it sums numbers in each row and prints the sum. But I need to print even the row with the biggest sum. Can someone please help me? Thanks. http://onlinemovies.pw

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    static int array [10][10];
    int i, j, m, n, sum = 0;

    printf ("Enter the order of the matrix\n");
    scanf ("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf ("Enter the co-efficients of the matrix \n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            scanf ("%d", &array [i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) 
        {
            sum = sum + array[i][j] ;
        }
        printf ("Sum of the %d row is = %d\n", i, sum);
        sum = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable and intialize it with a minimum value, if those values are always positive you can initialize it to 0:

```
int max = 0;
```

if not, you can use `INT_MIN` defined in `<limits.h>`

```
#include <limits.h>
...
int max = INT_MIN;
```

then use it in your loop:

```
int max = INT_MIN, imax = 0;

for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) 
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) 
    {
        sum = sum + array[i][j] ;
    }
    printf ("Sum of the %d row is = %d\n", i, sum);
    if (sum > max) {
        max = sum;
        imax = i;
    }
    sum = 0;
}
printf ("Max row (%d) is = %d\n", imax, max);
```